# Where LSI MegaRAID log files stored on Linux

Tags: linux, logs, raid

I'm trying to figure out where all the logs are stored for a LSI MegaRAID controller on a Linux system. I know how to query, dump, and clear the logs using `storcli`. However, even if the logs are cleared, you can still access the deleted entries with `type=includedeleted`.

So I'd like to know where all of this data is being stored so it doesn't eat up space in a partition that isn't sufficiently sized to handle that.

I've looked under `/var/log`, but don't see anything there.

Comment: You could run `storcli` under `strace` or `sysdig` and see what files it touches.

Comment: In the vast majority of cases this kind of hardware logs are stored in a [NVRAM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-volatile_random-access_memory).  They are not files on disk, you can only access them with some controller-specific program (in your case `storcli`).  Which makes sense, since your controller doesn't know, nor cares, about the OS you're running.

Comment: @SatoKatsura That makes sense. So I assume, then, that the controller truncates the logs automatically if they get too long.